# Class methods vs builder

Tags: c++

I have internal objects, which should'nt be used by client code :

```
class InternalA {};
class InternalB {};
```

I have public interface objects A, B, C. Internally, i need to construct objetcs InternalA from A and InternalB from B, but A and B can only be accessed by a pointer to base class C. I could use covariant virtual method but doing so, my Internals become public, and InternalA and InternalB are not really two subtytes of the same base class.
Or i could do something like that :

```
class C {
    // some data
public:
    C() {};
    // some pure virtual methods and virtual methods
virtual C *getConcrete(void) const =0;

};

class B : C {
public:
    //methods
    virtual B *getConcrete(void) { return static_cast<B>(this); };
};

class A : C {
public:
    //methods
    virtual A *getConcrete(void) { return static_cast<A>(this); };
};
```

And then use an internal builder with polymorphic method in A or B parameter.

Edit :
To build InternalA and InternalB, i can use a function/method like that :

```
void somefunction(A *a) {
    InternalA x(<using a->smthg>);
    // do stuffs
};
void somefunction(B *b) {
    InternalB x(using b->smthg>);
   //do stuffs
```

};

What do you think about this hack ?

Comment: And where does `InternalA` or `InternalB` come into play in your example?

Comment: An internal builder can build them from pointers to the objects A or B. But to build InternalA or InternalB, I need the concrete class A or B, I can't do this with abstract class C since I need to choose whether I'll build InternalA or InternalB

Comment: What kind of signature are you envisioning for this builder function? What kind of parameters will it receive to build the `A` or `B` object? But IMHO the `getConcrete` case if fine too eventhough eventually a little clunky.

Answer (score 0):

I think its impossible to solve this problem using only `class C`. To build `InternalA` or `InternalB` you need knowledge about A or B. At builder definition A or B must be defined. So I think you should use `dynamic_cast`. Or some kind of type id implemented by virtual functions if `dynamic_cast` is prohibited.

```
#include "A.h"

......

InternalA* buildInternalA(const C* c) {
    const A* a = dynamic_cast<const A*>(c);
    if (a)
        return new InternalA(a);
    return 0;
}
```

But where you use builder(in other cpp file), you don`t need definition of A and B, only declaration of builder:

```
class InternalA;
class C;
InternalA* buildInternalA(const C* c);
```